# Difference between 'or' and 'unless'

Tags: conjunctions, exam-questions

In my English examination there is a sentence :

> 'You must leave now ..... you will be late for school.

My teacher said that the answer is *'or'*, but I think the answer is *'unless'*, and she doesn't explain much. Therefore, I can't understand correctly. Would you mind explaining specifically for me.

Comment: It's *'or'*. It talks about the condition. If you want to use the conjunction 'unless', it should be: You will be late for school *unless* you leave (for it) now.

Comment: @MaulikV - great comment, it illustrates the issue nicely.

Comment: This condition is special one, isn't it ?

Comment: No, not a special one! You must run **or** you'll be caught by the dog....

Comment: Roughly, 'or' would have the *reason* **first** and the *result* **second** in order. In 'unless', it'll be *result* first and *reason* at second place. You must leave now (reason) **or** you'll be late (result). But - You'll be late (result) unless (reason) you leave now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence

> You must leave now or you will be late for school.

means *If you do not leave now, you will be late for school.* Changing the order of the clauses gives *You will be late for school if you do not leave now.* **If ... not** can often be replaced by **unless**, so you get

> You will be late for school unless you leave now.

In other words, in order to use **unless** you have to switch the order of the clauses.

**Or** functions here to introduce a consequence. It might be clearer to you if you think of it as being "or else".

Answer (score 1):

> Unless you buy a ticket, you cannot enter the movie theater.
>
> You cannot enter the movie theater unless you buy a ticket.

**unless** introduces a requirement, expressed as a clause with a tensed verb.

You can also express a requirement as a noun-phrase, using **without**.

> Without a ticket, you cannot enter the movie theater.
>
> You cannot enter the movie theater without a ticket.

Comment: It doesn't explain why "or" is correct answer. Which it is.

Comment: It explains why "unless" is the wrong answer. Which it is. Feel free to write your own answer, if you're more interested in setting the OP clear on "or".